# Python, logging pathname in decorator

Tags: python

When I logging an error in a decorator, the logging `pathname` is not what I want.

logging.conf:

```
[loggers]
keys=root
[handlers]
keys=console
[formatters]
keys=console
[logger_root]
...
[handler_console]
...
[formatter_console]
format=%(levelname)s - File "%(pathname)s", line %(lineno)s, %(funcName)s: %(message)s
```

Nomally, logging an error in file `/home/lizs/test/app.py`:

```
def app():
    try:
        a   # error, on line 12
    except Exception, err:
        logging.getLogger().error(str(err))
```

Debug message on console:

```
ERROR - File "/home/lizs/test/app.py", line 12, app: global name 'a' is not defined
```

The above logging `pathname`(/home/lizs/test/app.py) is what I want. But when I use a decorator:

`/home/lizs/test/app.py`:

```
from decorators import logging_decorator


@logging_decorator
def app():
   a
```

`/home/lizs/test/decorators.py`:

```
def logging_decorator(func):
    def error_log():
        try:
            func()  # on line 10
        except Exception, err:
            logging.getLogger().error(str(err))
    return error_log
```

The debug message:

```
ERROR - File "/home/lizs/test/decorators.py", line 10, error_log: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Now, the logging `pathname` is a pathname of the decorator (/home/lizs/test/decorators.py).

How to set the logging `pathname` to `/home/lizs/test/app.py` when I use decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your exception handler is one level upper than where the exception was initially raised, so you will have to examine the stacktrace and manually build a LogRecord with the correct file/line information:

```
def logging_decorator(func):
    def error_log():
        try:
            func()  # on line 10
        except Exception, err:
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]     # extract the current exception info
            exc_tup = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1]  # extract the deeper stack frame
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            # manually build a LogRecord from that stack frame
            lr = logger.makeRecord(logger.name,
                                   logging.ERROR, exc_tup[0], exc_tup[1],
                                   str(err), {}, None, exc_tup[2])
            logger.handle(lr)     # and ask the logging system to process it
    return error_log
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution:

Try this:

**app.py:**

```
from decorators import logging_decorator

@logging_decorator
def app():
    a

app()
```

**decorators.py:**

```
import logging
import inspect

#   init logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - File %(real_pathname)s,'
                              ' line %(real_lineno)s, %(real_funcName)s: %(message)s')
console_handle = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handle.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handle)


def logging_decorator(func):
    def error_log():
        try:
            func()
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error(err, extra={'real_pathname': inspect.getsourcefile(func),  # path to source file
                                     'real_lineno': inspect.trace()[-1][2],         # line number from trace
                                     'real_funcName': func.__name__})               # function name

    return error_log
```

### Explanation:

According to [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) you can pass a dictionary as `extra` argument *to populate the `__dict__` of the `LogRecord` created for the logging event with user-defined attributes. These custom attributes can then be used as you like*.

Thus, [because we can't modify `pathname` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862192/why-is-it-forbidden-to-override-log-record-attributes), this approach with `real_pathname` is most straight possible.

### Links:

- [`inspect.getsourcefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile)
- [`inspect.trace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.trace)
- [`logging.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

Comment: According to [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile),`inspect.getsourcefile ` return the name of the Python source file in which an object was defined. BUT this will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function. Is there any solution for  a built-in function?

Comment: @yi xiao, built-ins (e.g. `print`) are implemented in C, hence they're, as far as I know, unreachable with vanilla `Python`. Maybe someone with `CPython` background can answer your question.

Comment: How about using `os.path.abspath(func.__module__)` to get the `real_pathname `?